# grunt deploy not deploy to target

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

i'v try to deploy the grunt output folder ( dist ) to server space using [grunt-deploy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-deploy) in Jenkins. it return success message after grunt deploy.but it actually not deploy to given target.and there is option for username and password of server.so i think its not secure method .if yes give me a correct method for that.also there is  no option for source path . this is my deploy code.

```
deploy: {
liveservers: {
  options:{
    servers: [{
      host: 'host',
      port: 'port',
      username: 'user',
      password: 'pass'
    }],
    cmds_before_deploy: [],
    cmds_after_deploy: [],
    deploy_path: '/home/testdeploy'
  }
} }
```

please help me :(

Comment: please double check your deploy_path

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mkdir` command to create a `releases` subfolder:

```
cd /home/testdeploy
mkdir releases
```

then retry. The existence of `releases` is a hardcoded assumption in the source

**References**

- [grunt-deploy: deploy.js source](https://github.com/ZheFeng/grunt-deploy/blob/master/tasks/deploy.js#L61)